# How can I add a description to a Cloud Endpoint method?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

How can I add a description to a Cloud Endpoint method?

Just by observation I figured out the API explorer uses the methods docstring for the description.

[image]

In some cases we use decorators which prevent the doscring beeing parsed properly from the API explorer.

Code example:

```
@endpoints.method(ScoreRequestMessage, ScoreResponseMessage,
                  path='scores', http_method='POST',
                  name='scores.insert')
@do_some_checks
def scores_insert(self, request):
    """
    Exposes an API endpoint to insert a score for the current user.

    """
    entity = Score.put_from_message(request)
    return entity.to_message()
```

Is there a way to provide an endpoint method description for the API explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is taht the docstring is lost after applying decorators, you should use the decorator [`functools.wraps`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) inside your decorator. In that way you will preserve the function name and the docstring.